# How to get constraints from a body

Tags: matter.js

Is there any way of knowing what constraints is a body attached to? I want to create a constraint each time two bodies collide, but not each time they collide after that first constraint is already created

*UPDATE: Added proof of concept*

In my code, i create an array of pairs with duplicate values, and because i have a maximum of 1000 elements, each value is duplicated in x+y*1000 and y+x*1000 indexes so they won't overlay

```
// global array
var alreadyPaired = [];

// on collision check, i save which pair of values must be paired
Matter.Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', function(event) {
 var idA = event.pairs[i].bodyA.id;
 var idB = event.pairs[i].bodyB.id;

 if ( !alreadyPaired[idA*1000+idB] && !alreadyPaired[idB*1000+idA] ) {
  alreadyPaired[idA*1000+idB] = true;
  alreadyPaired[idB*1000+idA] = true;
 }
});
```

Comment: Worst case scenario, you could keep track of the constraints yourself with your own data structure.

Comment: I did it that way, but when i have hundreds of bodies on screen colliding, that eats a lot a resources because i have to check twice the possible members of the collission: one time for the "A Body" property and another one for the "B Body" property

Comment: I'm not sure I follow -- it should be a constant-time hash lookup on collision, probably just what MJS would do under the hood if it supported this feature (it might, I don't know). If you have a working proof of concept that's inefficient, could you share it so that there's a baseline to improve upon? Thanks.